# Before trigger time dependent action process builder

Tags: process-builder

I have created a time dependent action using process builder, it should notify 1 hr before the created date. How does this even possible to know that a particular record will get created after 1 hr?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce does not support time travel.

If you enqueue scheduled actions which would execute at a time in the past, Salesforce enqueues them for near-immediate execution following the event that caused the process to execute, such as inserting a record. See [this document](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_limits_scheduled_processing.htm&type=5):

> If a schedule evaluates to a time in the past, Salesforce executes the associated actions as soon as possible. Depending on how many actions Salesforce is processing at the time, actions are executed within one hour.